# Eclipse websphere dev tools plugin with dockerized websphere

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere, ibm-wdt

Is there a way to run WebSpehere9 traditional from *docker* container as *eclipse server* with *[IBM WebSphere Application Server V9.x Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v9x-developer-tools)* plugin?

[image: add new server]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WDT currently only has the Docker support for WebSphere Liberty server where it can discover running containers with Liberty server and allows you to create server to develop application in that scenario. This function is not available for WebSphere Application Server traditional in the current version of WDT.

Feel free to submit a feature enhancement request for this function from [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/help/submit-rfe/) and select *WebSphere Developer Tools* on the product field.